# Are all effected tables "locked" by mySQL transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I want to do a financial transaction but I am not really familiar with MySQL transaction feature.

I want to get sure that I am doing all things right. My goal is to "lock" my transactionHistory and transactionQueued table during my transaction in order to be sure that the account balance is correct and no other transaction can be inserted manipulate the balance / meanwhile.

```
SET autocommit=0;
START TRANSACTION;

IF (
SELECT SUM(amount) of transactionHistory WHERE account = 1
+
SELECT SUM(amount) of transactionsQueued WHERE account = 1)

 >= :amount)

INSERT INTO transactionHistory (account, amount) VALUES (1, -:amount);
INSERT INTO transactionHistory (account, amount) VALUES (2, :amount);

COMMIT;
```

Is it right that mySQL locks all effected tables? In this case transactionHistory and transactionsQueued.

I am using innoDB and this code is not part of a procedure.

Thank you!

Comment: your code 'as is' seems incorrect, does it belong to a stored procedure? Also, you have to tell us what is the database engine used for the involved tables (myisam/innodb/...?) Also 2, `START TRANSACTION` is implicit. (Be sure to use auto commit=0)

Comment: Okay thx. I am using innodb and this code is not part of a procedure. I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 4):

```
SET autocommit=0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

Both do basically the same thing, except that START TRANSACTION also realeses all the LOCKS hold by the session.

If you want to lock the records in TABLE(S), then you can either use SELECT...FOR UPDATE statement (that will lock all the records that falls into conditions written in that SELECT). You need to use this in a transaction.

Or you can LOCK the whole table. To lock the table, you can not use START TRANSACTION; however. You need to start the transaction like this:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES transactionHistory as t1 WRITE, transactionsQueued  as t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that you're using INNODB, the answer is no, the lock level is `ROW`, not `TABLE` (unlike MYISAM)

See this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

---

I think you already know it but your code is pseudo code and would not work like this. The IF statement is very procedural and needs to be included in a BEGIN END block, or maybe otherwise you could build an equivalent advanced `insert select` statement.

Comment: Yes I am using innodb and it is pseuocode. Oh, so what can I do to get this working as expected / to prevent changes in the mentioned tables.

Can the lock level changed to the whole table?

Comment: yes, but why would you want to do so? How long do you want the lock to persist?

Comment: Okay take this php snippet for example

if (user->getBalance() >= $sendAmount) {
  sendAmount(userID,receiverID,$sendAmount);
}

my sendAmount function should execute the query I wrote in my question.

If I would not lock the table there is a possibility that this transaction can be done twice when it is executed in quick succession. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Locking does not prevent the transaction to be executed twice, it would only delay the second one.

Comment: Okay but when I check for the balance in my quere and only proceed with the inserts when the user has sufficient funds it would work fine now, right?

Comment: Moreover, if you locked the tables, a subsequent execution would **not** see the transactionHistory updated (due to isolation level consistency) and might deduced wrongly that it has to insert again in the table.

Comment: is it for your private backoffice or a public interface where you don't control who clicks the button that calls this procedure?

Comment: It is for a public website who a user can initiate a transaction by clicking a button so it is very important for me

Comment: Then you have to initiate a semaphore process, to ensure that when it is running, a second call should be rejected. This is going beyond your prime question and I suggest you open another one. Good luck

Comment: One more short question:
Can this be the solution for my problem? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Oh, no, not at all. If the user clicks twice on the button it will increase the balance twice. You actually want to go away from this. What you need is a script that can be executed only once at a time

Comment: @Sebas can loack and transactions both combined can solve his problem , i am also having same problem.